# The characterization of pdf document of indexing service

Tags: asp-classic, indexing-service

Anyone knows searching pdf document is/is not support the attribute "characterication" of the document?"

the code is

```
q.columns="doctitle, filename, size, write, rank, directory, path, characterization"
```

the search result of characterization is blank. I'm finding a method to print the short summary of the pdf document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that searching PDF documents does support the "characterization" field. [This thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/599264) describes the same problem. The user had to uninstall the iFilter, install an earlier version, and make a registry edit in order to get the search to function properly.